# How to return 'Snake Eyes' or the Values using React Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

*8a. Below the ReactDOM Render method, create another function component called DiceRoll.
8b. Inside the function component use Math.random to return a random number between 1 and 6 and set it to const variable called "die1"
8c. Below the die1 variable, use Math.random again to return a random number between 1 and 6 and set it to const variable called "die2"
8d. Below the die2 variable, have the DiceRoll function component return an h1 element. Inside the h1 element use a TERNARY that…
Sets the text for the h1 to "SNAKE EYES" if both die1 and die2 are equal to 1
Or
If either die1 or die2 is NOT equal to 1 sets the text for the h1 to the values for each die like shown in this example: 2 & 5.
8e. Below the DiceRoll function component, use the ReactDOM Render method again to render/display the DiceRoll function component in the div with the id of "root" in the HTML file*

^^ Question

My current code >>

```
// 8a
function DiceRoll() {
    // 8b
    const die1 = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 )
    // 8c
    const die2 = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 )
    // 8d
    return (
        <h1>
            if (die1 =! 1) {
                return ('Snake Eyes');
            }
            else {
                return({die1} & {die2})
            }
        </h1>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track, but your conditional on your `if` statement isn't quite right. Try this:

```js
if ((die1 == 1) && (die2 == 1)) {
    return ('Snake Eyes');
}
else {
    return({die1} & {die2});
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1:5500/FrontEnd/React/FunctionComponentsExercise/app.js: Unexpected token (134:20)
  132 |         <h1>
  133 |             if ((die1 == 1) && (die2 == 1)) {
> 134 |                     return ('Snake Eyes');
      |                     ^
  135 |                     }
  136 |                     else {
  137 |                         return({die1} & {die2});

Comment: That's the error I'm getting using chromedev tools!

Comment: Got it - you were right, I needed to adjust some of the code before to make it work! Thank You